# Updating multiple paths or node at same time in firebase with node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am looping over the Pending status' bought Products.
Now, I want to take the amount from the bought product and add that in seller's balance.
Once, Balance has been added successfully, next step is to update status of bought product from Pending to Approved.
Following code i wrote to fulfil above operations

```
const userRef = db.ref().child('USER');
const boughProductRef = db.ref().child('BOUGHT_PRODUCT');
boughProductRef.orderByChild('status').equalTo('Pending').on("value", snapshot => {

    if (!!snapshot && !!snapshot.val()) {
        _.forEach(Object.keys(snapshot.val()), key => {
            var boughtProduct = snapshot.val()[key];
            var sellerId = _.split(_.get(boughtProduct, 'productId'), "/")[0];
            var updateBoughtProduct = boughProductRef.child(key);
            userRef.child(sellerId)
                .once("value")
                .then(snap => {
                    if (!!snap && snap.val()) {
                        var user = snap.val();
                        userRef.child(sellerId).update({
                            balance: user.balance + boughtProduct.amount
                        })
                    }
                }).then(() => {
                    updateBoughtProduct.update({
                        status: "Approved"
                    })
                }).catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error, 'error');
                })
        })

    }
});
```

This codes run every midnight in cron job.

Is this right way to do it ? or there are some other ways to do it ?
I am new in field of firebase and javascript.

Comment: I believe batch writes are the way to go if you have several writes to do at once.

Comment: If the code works and does what you want, then it's the right way to do it. If you have concerns about the code, please be specific about what those are.